# SqlServer Compact "is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: sql-server-ce, .net-4.5

I have a website I'm working and im using Sql compact 4 sp1 for my database

I have sql compact installed on my pc and it works fine, however I am having problems trying to deploy the site to a host.

I have installed the nuget package "Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" and have verified that the x86 and amd64 directories it creates in my bin folder are deployed

however, when i try to visit the website, i get the following error

> is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

and the beginning of the stack trace reads

> [BadImageFormatException:  is not a valid Win32 application.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)]
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) +0
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.UnmanagedLibraryHelper..ctor(String fileName)
>   +53    System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethodsHelper..ctor(String modulePath) +28
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadValidLibrary(String
>   modulePath) +372

I have found one suggestion that says i should go into iis, find the application, go to advanced settings and check the enable 32-bit applications, which i havent done because i dont currently have access to the server, but is this really necessary, sql ce has x86 and x64 dlls so why would it need to run in 32 bit mode?

Comment: The folder names should be AMD64 and x86, and contain the correct DLL files.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part, the nuget package creates these folders and adds the dlls in and adds the relevant entry into the web.config

Comment: Wrong files in the x86 folder? (look at sqlceme40.dll)

Comment: The files were added via nuget so i cant see how they could get mixed up

Comment: In the end i just created a new project and slowly added all the pieces back into it, worked fine and im none the wiser as to why it didnt work in the first place